# When part of migration fails, why doesn't it "undo"?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

Say I have this migration:

```
class MigrateStuff < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :contacts, :receive_newsletter, :boolean, :default => false
    add_index :contacts, :receive_newsletter

    for t in SomeOtherThing.all
      #... do stuff in here
    end
  end

  def down
    #...
  end
end
```

So I add a column and index. Then I work some data into the new column. What happens if some portion in my `for` loop fails? The column/index is not removed. I tried adding this to a transaction:

```
class MoveEmailRecipientsToContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Volunteer.transaction do
      add_column :contacts, :receive_newsletter, :boolean, :default => false
      add_index :contacts, :receive_newsletter

      for t in SomeOtherThing.all
        #... do stuff in here
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    #...
  end
end
```

So an exception occurs in the `for` block, doesn't this cause the transaction to roll-back? But the column and index remains!

What's the proper way to handle this?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support transactional changes to the schema. The *easiest* way to fix it is just to switch to Postgres. They're largely compatible, especially if you're using Arel to build your queries.

Comment: Good to know. So why wouldn't rake/rails be smart and undo the schema changes? I guess it could get messy.

Answer (score 0):

The other way would be rollback manually by raising ActiveRecord::Rollback exception.

```
raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
```

when you want to rollback.

Comment: Would a "normal" exception, raised within the transaction block, cause the transaction to be rolled back?

Comment: No other exceptions will not roll it back

Comment: @techvineet, *No other exceptions will not roll it back* : **this is wrong**. Any exception will cause a rollback. The difference is that if you raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback`, then the exception will not be re-raised (thus you cannot handle that exception); all other exceptions will cause a rollback and it will bubble up to your app.

Comment: @techvineet, thanks I know how to use SO. :) Your answer doesn't answer my question. I knew how to rollback in a transaction, but not how to rollback schema changes - which coreyward explained is not possible with MySQL. Thanks for your answer, though.